# Javascript function returns undefined value, even though the variable has been defined and fetched from IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, progressive-web-apps

So, I am using IndexedDB, which has some data. I wanted to search through it and once there's a match, I returned a corresponding data. Here's the code:

```
function code1(sname){
        var db;
        var request1 = indexedDB.open("footballDatabase",1);
        request1.onsuccess = function (evt) {
            db = request1.result;
            var objectStore = db.transaction("teamsData").objectStore("teamsData");
            objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
                var cursor = event.target.result;
                if (cursor) {
                    var name = cursor.value.name;
                    if(sname === name){
                        var code = cursor.value.code;
                        console.log(sname + " " +code);
                        return code;
                    }else{
                        cursor.continue();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

This is the function call:

```
alert(code1("Chelsea FC"));
```

The console shows everything properly when I logged the results. But when returned, it shows undefined. 
I know that undefined in JS means, the variable hasn't been properly initialized before. But in this case, it is, because it logs the same variable just alright.

I know, I did something wrong, I just can't figure out what. Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: It's because code1 is an async function, and alert is not waiting for the response. And as you return nothing outside of the onsuccess callback function, the result will be undefined.
Try 'alert(code);' instead of 'return code;' inside the callback.

Comment: @BenceFarkas yeah, alert(code) does work, but I want the value of code returned for various reasons.

Comment: Check the "Callback hell" section:
https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee

Comment: A `return` statement only returns from the function it is immediately contained within.

Comment: Sanjay, the main idea is that when we have some async operation that you want to return data, this data *can only be referenced in the callback for the async operation*. Alternatively, you could explore the `async/await` pattern to make it "look like" you are returning a value and then using it "immediately"...but its still worth grokking the callback pattern of async flow.